# How can I transfer ownership of a PS3 account?

Tags: ps3

My father created a PS3 account for himself and a second one using his information (e-mail, billing information, name, etc.) for me to use a while back.  Now I recently moved out, bought my own PS3, and have my own e-mail now and would like to edit the account he made for me, with his consent, so I can use it as my own.

However, I'm not sure how it works. If you edit the e-mail address for an account will it still be under the original account owner's name?  If so, is there a way to change who owns the account?

Comment: why don't you just keep on using the account with your father's details?

Comment: He won't allow me to use it on my own PS3 because the account is on his own console, with his billing information which is important not to give away.  He says he won't agree to edit the billing information and e-mail if it would still be under his name as the owner since it would still be considered his property no matter who's e-mail and billing info is on it.  Can the name of who owns the account be edited as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change pretty much everything associated with the account with notable exceptions being PSN ID and your birth date (used as a secret question in password recovery procedure).

Since authorization is done via email, you need to ask your dad to:

1. Remove his billing info from account in question;
2. Change account e-mail to your e-mail (there will be e-mail change confirmation link to old e-mail, IIRC);
3. Info about which birthdate was used then creating account.

That's it, after this actions you pretty much "own" the account.

P.S. be warned however, that account transfer/selling is prohibited by [PSN terms of service](http://www.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/terms-of-service/):

> You may not sell, buy, trade, or otherwise transfer your Online ID, SEN Account or any personal access to SEN through any means or method, including by use of web sites.

If you are unlucky enough it's possible that account will be banned.

Answer (score 0):

PSN accounts' names can be changed on both [PS3](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/255) and [PS4](http://www.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/How_to_Edit_Your_Profile), although it's only visible to anyone else on PS4. The email address is [changeable too](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/255). You can [remove the account's billing info](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/346) as well.

The one thing you can't change is your username/online handle.