# How to change ownership of PS3?

Tags: ps3

A friend has passed, and his wife gave his PS3 to me. How can I change ownership to my own account?

Comment: I'm sorry; hope y'all will be okay. Do you have his sign in information, or is it locked?

Comment: Does this help? [How can I transfer ownership of a PS3 account?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152432/how-can-i-transfer-ownership-of-a-ps3-account)